# CakePHP gettext, multiple languages inside a view file

Tags: php, cakephp, gettext

In my CakePHP 2.4 application,
Inside my controller files I set different languages like this:

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language', "eng");
Configure::write('Config.language', "eng");
```

I use this in my view files:

```
echo __("Hello");
```

But sometimes I need gettext for different languages.

for example I need an output like this inside my ctp file:

```
Hola    
Bonjour   
Алло
```

How can I get this output ?

Only possibility I can think of is:
- Setting Config.language in session
- Making a gettext like this: `__("Hello")`
- Changing Config.language again
- Making a gettext like this: `__("Hello")`
- Changing Config.language again
- Making a gettext like this: `__("Hello")`

But inside view files it is not possible to use SessionHelper's set methods. Only get methods can be used. I don't prefer to use raw PHP session variable like `$_SESSION`. But I need to get different translations for a string inside my view file.

How can I obtain this ?

Comment: The Session helper is a bit of a false restraint - you can use the `CakeSession` static interface from anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__()` is only wrapper for `I18n::translate`.

Use "plain" [I18n::translate](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-I18n.html#_translate) (language param)

Comment: Or write the language [to where the I18n class looks for it](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php#L148-L151) before calling `__()`. +1.

Comment: This works good. Thank you. `I18n::translate("My sentence", null, null, 6, null, "fr")`